# Calender.getTime() not showing the date time of given timeZone

Tags: java, timezone

I am in timeZone +05:30 hrs and I want the time zone of Europe, so I am trying this:-

```
    TimeZone tmz=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Zurich");
    Calendar calender=new GregorianCalendar(tmz);
    Date date=calender.getTime();
    String datestr=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss").format(date);
    System.out.println(datestr+" CST");
```

But I am getting my timezone's time instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the time zone *in the `SimpleDateFormat`*. A `Date` value doesn't have a time zone, so your initial code is fairly pointless - you could just call `new Date()`.

Note that your format string is incorrect too - you're using minutes instead of months, and you're using a 12-hour clock which almost certainly isn't what you want.

I suspect your code should be:

```
TimeZone tmz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Zurich");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(tmz);
String datestr = format.format(new Date());
```

As an aside, if you *possibly* can, I would avoid using all these classes - use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) if you're stuck on Java 7 or earlier, and the `java.time` package if you're using Java 8. They're far, far better date/time APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..
To display the time according to the time zone you've set for the `Calendar`, you could use a `DateFormat` object and do something like the following:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class PrintDate
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      TimeZone tmz=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Zurich");

      DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
      df.setTimeZone(tmz);

      System.out.println("Current time in Europe--> " +
                         df.format(Calendar.getInstance(tmz).getTime()));
   }
}
```

Comment: what is tz you used in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java8 with new Clock API you can get the same using below

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich");
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now(zone);
```

and `DateTimeFormatter` has many options to format the date and time

**EDIT**

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now(zoneId);
```

For getting date and time,

Comment: Question asked for date-time, not time-of-day.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33051774/642706) is correct and direct, and should be accepted.

The [answer by Saravana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33052017/642706) follows Skeet’s suggestion to use the new java.time framework. But that Answer has time-of-day and the Question asked for date-time. Thus this Answer here.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is bundled with Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). These new classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. They are a vast improvement over the troublesome old classes, java.util.Date/.Calendar et al.

Current date-time is easy to get. Specify your desired/expected [time zone by name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). If omitted, your your JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Zurich" );
ZonedDateTime nowZurich = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneId );
```

You can generate a String representation of that date-time value. By default, the `toString` method uses the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatting but extends the standard by appending the zone name in brackets.

```
String outputStandard = nowZurich.toString (); // ISO 8601 format, extended by appending name of zone in brackets.
```

Alternatively, you can use a [localized format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html), or even [define your own format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html). Specify a [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
Locale localeFrenchSwitzerland = new Locale.Builder ().setLanguage ( "fr" ).setRegion ( "CH" ).build ();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale ( localeFrenchSwitzerland );
String outputFrenchSwitzerland = nowZurich.format ( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "outputStandard: " + outputStandard );
System.out.println ( "outputFrenchSwitzerland: " + outputFrenchSwitzerland );
```

When run.

> outputStandard: 2015-10-11T02:39:58.287+02:00[Europe/Zurich]
>
> outputFrenchSwitzerland: dimanche, 11. octobre 2015 02.39. h CEST

If you really need a java.util.Date for interoperability with other classes not yet updated for java.time, convert.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from ( nowZurich.toInstant () );
```